# Using javascript, how do I duplicate the behavior of a div acting as a select element when clicking outside the element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, click

I needed to create a pseudo-select element that displays columns for each row in the select. Since HTML does not allow the `<option>` tag to contain HTML, I had to take this approach.

One of the features of a normal select element is that it folds up when you click outside the element, no matter where the user clicks. It can be within the document, it can be in the address bar, or wherever. I am having trouble duplicating that behavior. Controlling inside the document is easy. But clicking in the address bar or even in the developer/console window, it doesn't work.

Please find my code below and a working fiddle.

```
<style>
        .selectedOrder {
            height: 30px; 
            display:none; 
        }

    /* class applies to select element itself, not a wrapper element */
    .select-css {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #444;
        line-height: 1.3;
        padding: .6em 1.4em .5em .8em;
        /* width: 100%; */
        max-width: 100%; /* useful when width is set to anything other than 100% */
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.04);
        border-radius: .5em;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        background-color: #fff;
        /* note: bg image below uses 2 urls. The first is an svg data uri for the arrow icon, and the second is the gradient. 
            for the icon, if you want to change the color, be sure to use `%23` instead of `#`, since it's a url. You can also swap in a different svg icon or an external image reference
            
        */
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23007CB2%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E'),
          linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
        background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
        /* arrow icon position (1em from the right, 50% vertical) , then gradient position*/
        background-position: right .7em top 50%, 0 0;
        /* icon size, then gradient */
        background-size: .65em auto, 100%;
    }
    /* Hide arrow icon in IE browsers */
    .select-css::-ms-expand {
        display: none;
    }
    /* Hover style */
    .select-css:hover {
        border-color: #888;
    }
    /* Focus style */
    .select-css:focus {
        border-color: #aaa;
        /* It'd be nice to use -webkit-focus-ring-color here but it doesn't work on box-shadow */
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px rgba(59, 153, 252, .7);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px -moz-mac-focusring;
        color: #222; 
        outline: none;
    }

    /* Set options to normal weight */
    .select-css option {
        font-weight:normal;
    }

    /* Support for rtl text, explicit support for Arabic and Hebrew */
    *[dir="rtl"] .select-css, :root:lang(ar) .select-css, :root:lang(iw) .select-css {
        background-position: left .7em top 50%, 0 0;
        padding: .6em .8em .5em 1.4em;
    }

    /* Disabled styles */
    .select-css:disabled, .select-css[aria-disabled=true] {
        color: graytext;
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22graytext%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E'),
          linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
    }

    .select-css:disabled:hover, .select-css[aria-disabled=true] {
        border-color: #aaa;
    }
</style>

<div id="orderSelectContainer">
    <div id="selectedOrder" class="selectedOrder select-css" style="width: 533px; display: block;">
        <div class="currentSelectedOrder" data-value="45628" style="float: left;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 1</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55628</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px">  </span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="orderSelect" class="select-css" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1000; background-image: none; display: none;">
        <div class="orderContainer">
            <div class="order" data-value="45628" style="float: left; background: white;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 1</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55628</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px">  </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="orderContainer">
            <div class="order" data-value="45536" style="float: left; background: lightblue;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 2</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55536</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px"> Bad UPCs</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="orderContainer">
            <div class="order" data-value="45682" style="float: left; background: white;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 3</span><span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55682</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px"> Bad UPCs</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="orderContainer">
            <div class="order" data-value="45625" style="float: left; background: white;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 4</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55625</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px">  </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="orderContainer">
            <div class="order" data-value="45556" style="float: left; background: white;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 5</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55556</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px"> Bad UPCs</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both"><br>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).on(`click`, `.order`, function() {
        if ($(this).data(`value`) !== $(`#selectedOrder >.currentSelectedOrder`).data(`value`)) {
            $(`#orderContainer`).html(``);
        }
        $(`#selectedOrder`).html($(this).prop(`outerHTML`)).find(`.order`).removeClass(`order`).css(`background`, ``).addClass(`currentSelectedOrder`);
        $(`.order`).css(`background`, `white`);
        $(this).css(`background`, `lightblue`);
        $(`#selectedOrder`).show();
        $(`#orderSelect`).hide();
    });

    $(document).on(`click`, `#selectedOrder`, function(e) {
        console.log(`selected order click`);
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(`#orderSelect`).toggle();
    });
    
    $(document).on(`mouseenter`, `.order`, function() {
        $(`.order`).css(`background`, `white`);
        $(this).css(`background`, `lightblue`);
    });

    $(document).on(`mouseexit`, `.order`, function() {
        $(this).css(`background`, `white`);
    });

    $(document).on(`click`, function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.id);
        $(`#orderSelect`).hide(); 
    });

<script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/schmidtc63/xu8zgpc9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Window: blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/blur_event) can be used as it will fire any time the window loses focus.

```
    $(window).on(`blur`, function(e) {
        $(`#orderSelect`).hide(); 
    });
```

Comment: I also put a tabindex and onblur on the div and that duplicated everything to make it act like a standard select element.